# my hdfs always report to many corrupted blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have a cluster running hdfs (hadoop 2.6.0) , but its name node reported to me an error about missing blocks:

> There are 102 missing blocks. The following files may be corrupted:

when I jump to name node and read log in (namenode file logs) I got many warnings like:

> Error report from DatanodeRegistration(10.3.24.71, datanodeUuid=b1aa43eb-bd9c-4e1a-b919-d7c99ad0fcdf, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-9f27dfea-17f6-41eb-95d2-50424dc78fa9;nsid=197210444;c=0):
>
> Can't send invalid block BP-352432948-10.3.24.65-1433821675295:blk_1074188011_949972

Is that problem with my hdd or something else?

Comment: Could you attach more logs about the block with id blk_1074188011_949972 ?

Comment: @tnk_peka:Was below answer was useful?

Answer (score 1):

[As described by this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/How-to-fix-missing-and-underreplicated-blocks/ta-p/36491)

**Cause**

Some file(s) in your HDFS file system have become corrupted either by losing their last block replica or simply being underreplicated.

NOTE: there is a big risk of this happening with temporary files or bogus sample data generated by teragen, because frequently those file will have a replication factor set to 1 by default and if the datanode hosting that one replica goes down, the file is irreparably corrupted (eg. lost).

**Troubleshooting Steps**

To get the full details of the files which are causing your problem, you can run the following command:

```
  $ hdfs fsck / -files -blocks -locations
```

The output of that command will identify the replication factor set on your corrupted files.

There are different ways you can avoid this problem depending on your data blocks..

1) The condition could just be transient, if you have a data under-replicated it should just automatically replicate the blocks to other data nodes to match the replication factor

2) if it is not replicating on your own run a balancer (do NOT run the HDFS balancer if you use HBase!)

3) you can manually set replication on a specific file which is under replicated to something higher than it currently is, coaxing the cluster to create more replicas.

4) if it is just a temp file which is created while running the job when your speculative execution tasks are high, make the speculative execution tasks nearly match the replication factor so that it wouldn't complain about the temp files after the job run.

As a last resort, if you are SURE these files are not needed and would like to just eliminate the error, you can run this command to automatically delete the corrupted files:

```
$ hdfs fsck / -delete
```